# Matplotlib, how to connect with a line annotations if a condition is met?

Tags: python, matplotlib, draw

I have three lists, one containing a set of symbols (characters) named "Atype", a second one "el" containing a set of numbers, each corresponding to the position+1 of an element in "AType" and another one containing sets of coordinates (x,y) named "XYcoord".  I want to annotate the characters of AType in a plot, placing every element of AType in the position (on the plot) indicated by the corresponding (x,y) pair in XYCoord.  This has not been a problem, but I would like to draw a connecting line between the letters when the distance between pairs of points is less than a value "BMax".
So far, this is what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for x in range(1, NCenter+1): # NCenter is the number of elements in AType and XYcoord.
    xposcoord, yposcoord = XYcoord[x-1][0]/100.0, XYcoord[x-1][1]/100.0
    ax.annotate('%s' % (AType[el[x-1]-1]), xy=(xposcoord, yposcoord), 
                xycoords='axes fraction')

plt.show()
```

I get a plot that looks like:
[image: Plot showing letters with no connections]
Now, I would like to draw a connection line between letters if distances between them is less than BMax.  I previously defined a function that returns the distance between points "dist_betwn_points(x1, y1, x2, y2)" so, I know by placing an if statement somewhere, like:

```
if dist_betwn_points(x1, y1, x2, y2) < BMax:
```

will help, but I have tried several ways, and have not been successful in defining the "ax.annotate(...)" part, to draw lines between the letters.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have an example. I hope it help you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_lines(x,y):
    ax = plt.gca()
    for j in range(len(x)):
        for i in range(j,len(x)):
            distance = np.sqrt((x[i]-x[j])**2+(y[i]-y[j])**2)
            if distance < 0.2 and distance > 0:
                ax.annotate('', xy=(x[i], y[i]), xytext=(x[j], y[j]),
                            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', 
                                            shrink=0.1,
                                            width=1),
                            textcoords='data',
                            )
n = 30
x,y = np.random.rand(n), np.random.rand(n)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

make_lines(x,y)

ax.plot(x,y,'ro',markersize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it did help me a lot, finally today I solved my problem, this was a great example, I did some changes to adjust it to my specific needs but it pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks again!